# Wouldn't more Altruists and Announcers to help growth of the site?

Tags: feature-request

There aren't many people with high enough reputation to offer up bounties on their questions, but I think that bounties do encourage more answers.

Also, bounties, combined with Tweets and other forms of promotion will help draw more visitors.

It is my suggestion that our community members with 1000+ reputations try to engage in the two activities of announcing and assigning bounties (justly). I am in full appreciation of the few members who are highly active which has helped this site develop.

Taking it further, could we respectfully request that our most esteemed members make an attempt to assign one bounty per week, assuming, of course that there are questions worthy of bounty?

And, also, *all* members who have a sizeable Twitter following or Facebook friends, please share at least your own questions. Rewrite them so they fit Twitter, and (IMO) fit the fully spelled out URL up to the question ID, but skipping the HTML filename which is not necessary. URL-shortened links are clicked through less frequently than those you can eyeball to confirm trustworthiness.

Example:

(I used the StackExchange nomenclature because it has recognition among various disciplines more so than "Pro Webmaster" does.)

[image]

Comment: Tumbleweed! Woo! ;-)  I wasn't shooting for it though.